# Word for a owing a free pass on withholding judgment

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, slang

The word is on the tip of my tongue and I'm pretty sure it ends with "ie or y."

The idea is a friend had a gracious attitude when I did something stupid, so now I want to return the favor.  So I want to say, "it's ok, I owe you a ____".

Something along the lines of a free pass.  But there's a slang (I think) word for this that I'm trying to think of.

Comment: You owe them a *favour*?

Comment: Urban Dictionary suggests [immunity](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=free+pass) as a synonym for *free pass* but that wouldn't really fit here.

Comment: I owe you a freebie?

Comment: shoulder to cry on? a *hearing*? a *[biggie](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/biggie)*?

Comment: According to Merriam-Webster, a _gimme_ is "a short putt in golf conceded to an opponent in casual or match play." Also from golf, a _mulligan_ is "a free shot sometimes given a golfer in informal play when the previous shot was poorly played."

Comment: You're looking for "***freebie***".

Answer (score 5):

*[Freebie](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/freebie)*:

> noun
>
> informal
>   A thing that is provided or given free of charge:
>
> <sub>ODO</sub>

*It's OK, I owe you a freebie.*

Answer (score 1):

Mercy is an appropriate word.

Merriam Webster defines it as:

"kind or forgiving treatment of someone who could be treated harshly"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this one.But ***courtesy*** might fit your description.

Comment: Why don't you describe *why* you think your suggestion is a good fit?  You could quote a dictionary and then tie back that definition to the needs expressed in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Compensation would work I guess

Comment: Hello, 0x2B, and welcome to EL&U. Your answer seems as reasonable as some of the other suggestions here, but you can strengthen it by adding a definition (ideally a linked one) from a reputable reference work that indicates why _compensation_ might be suitable. Thanks!